# How to get success factors version via API?

Tags: api, version, sap-successfactors

I'm using SAP Success factors API that i found:
I'm sending get request to this host https://user_name.successfactors.eu/sfapi/v1/soap12?wsdl with relevant credentials and i'm getting an XML but without the user version (something like b1808 (for august 2018).

Do you know how can i get this version?
Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, SFAPI is deprecated or will be deprecated soon and I personally expect SFAPI to reach "end of life" within the next releases. But that is my personal opinion, officially SAP recommends using OData API but does not restrict using SFAPI: [Page 8/9 for Deprecation Info](https://help.sap.com/doc/0bd2f6fea0154ac6aacd44f1cacbfc71/1811/en-US/SF_HCM_SFAPI_DEV.pdf)

I am quite familiar with OData API and did not find any version information, I assume this also applies to SFAPI. The assumption relies on the information, that the APIs are always downward-compatible, this means you don't have to develop for a separate version, you could developt against the API no matter of the underlying version of the system.

If you really require to split according to the version of your system you could only separate by your system. This means if you have a two-tier environment, you need to know where you are requesting the API and develop against it. Furthermore systems differ from 3 to 8 weeks, 4 times in a year, but still they are compatible.

Maybe you could describe your goal a little bit in detail, then I might help to find a good solution.

Comment: I just want to get my account current version via an API and without go through the web-site. Thanks

Comment: as written above, there is no service or API fullfilling your requirement .. sorry.